# Simple algebra loss calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Kylie bought an item for $x$ and sold it for \$10.56. If Kylie incurred a loss of $x$ percent, find $x$.

The answer is apparently "12 or 88" but I cannot see how they got there. I have tried
$$\frac{10.56-x}{x}=x$$
But the result is no where near what the answer is.

Comment: this amounts to solving the quadratic $\space x^2+x-10.56=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve the equation $$\frac{x-10.56}{x}=\frac{x}{100},$$
and cross-multiplying and bringing all the terms to the right side of the equation gives $$x^2-100x+1056=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

You must solve for :
$$ \frac{x-10.56}{x}=x $$